# WPF ListView with horizontal arrangement of items?

Tags: wpf, listview, layout

I want to lay out items in a ListView in a similar manner to the WinForms ListView in List mode. That is, where items are laid out not just vertically but horizontally in the ListView as well.

I don't mind if the items are laid out like this:

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9

Or like this:

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

As long as they are presented both vertically and horizontally in order to maximize the use of available space.

The closest I could find was this question:

[How do I make WPF ListView items repeat horizontally, like a horizontal scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359217/how-do-i-make-wpf-listview-items-repeat-horizontally-like-a-horizontal-scrollbar)

Which only lays out the items only horizontally.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

It sounds like what you are looking for is a [WrapPannel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel.aspx), which will lay the items out horizontally until there is no more room, and then move to the next line, like this:

([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295081.aspx))
[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Cc295081.b1c415fb-9a32-4a18-aa0b-308fca994ac9(en-us,Expression.10).png](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Cc295081.b1c415fb-9a32-4a18-aa0b-308fca994ac9(en-us,Expression.10).png)

You also could use a [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx), which will lay the items out in a set number of rows or columns.

The way we get the items to arange using these other panels in a ListView, ListBox, or any form of ItemsControl is by changing the [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) property. By setting the ItemsPanel you can change it from the default StackPanel that is used by ItemsControls.  With the WrapPanel we also should set the widths as [shown here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748859(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
<ListView>
   <ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
            ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
            MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsPanel>
...
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had tried using a WrapPanel previously, as suggested by Dennis, but the Width binding is needed which the example I was working from didn't have.

Comment: Apparently the only important thing is the Width. The others are optional.

Comment: I had some problems with **WrapPanel** when the window is maximized, so, I changed **Width** with **MaxWidth** and now it works smoothly.

Comment: Is there any way to set item width automatically in this sample so it would correspond to the maximal ListView item width?

Answer (score 26):

I recently research how to achieve this in WPF and found a good solution. What I wanted was to the replicate the List mode in Windows Explorer, i.e. top-to-bottom, then left-to-right.

Basically what you want to do override the `ListBox.ItemsPanel` property to use a WrapPanel with it's orientation set to Vertical.

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>      
      <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

However this **WILL** be slow when loading a large data set as it the wrap panel is not virtualised. This is important. So this task now becomes a little more as now you need to write your own VirtualizedWrapPanel by extending VirtualizedPanel and implementing IScrollInfo.

```
public class VirtualizedWrapPanel : VirtualizedPanel, IScrollInfo
{
   // ...
}
```

This is as far as I got in my research before having to go off to another task. If you want more information or examples, please comment.

**UPDATE**. Ben Constable's has a great [series on how to implement IScrollInfo](http://blogs.msdn.com/bencon/archive/2006/01/05/509991.aspx).

There are 4 articles in total. A really good read.

I have since implemented a virtualized wrap panel, it is not an easy task even with the help of the above series of articles.

Comment: shouldn't the source be ItemsPanelTemplate wrapped in ListBox.ItemsPanel and not the other way around? Your version does not compile.

Comment: @Sam: You are correct. I must have written that code directly into StackOverflow (i.e. did not check it). Thank-you for picking that up.

Comment: Ahh I can't really figure out how to write this `VirtualizedWrapPanel` Ben's tutorial is a bit unclear when to put code where. To me it is a bit confusing how I then should implement this `VirtualizedWrapPanel`. Where is `VirtualizedPanel` coming from anyway?

Answer (score 10):

In my case, the best option was to use:

```
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                    MaxHeight="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualHeight), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                               ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                               MinHeight="{Binding ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                               ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

This gave me a decent analog to Windows Explorer's List option

Answer (score 4):

for left to right then top to bottom use

```
      <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
                     MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay, 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                       AncestorType={x:Type er:MainWindow}}}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Dennis's answer, about the WrapPanel losing Virtualization, I have found a nice class that correctly implements this. While the suggested post by Ben  Constable ([Part 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bencon/2006/01/06/iscrollinfo-in-avalon-part-i/), [Part 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bencon/2006/01/06/iscrollinfo-in-avalon-part-i/), [Part 3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bencon/2006/01/06/iscrollinfo-in-avalon-part-i/), [Part 4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bencon/2006/01/06/iscrollinfo-in-avalon-part-i/)) is a nice introduction, I couldn't quite complete the task for a Wrap Panel.

Here is an implementation:
https://virtualwrappanel.codeplex.com/
I've tested it with  total of 3.300 video's and photo's, loading the list itself is of course a bit long, but eventually it is correctly virtualizing the list, no scroll lag whatsoever.

- There are some issues to this code, see the issues tab on the page above.

After adding the source code to your project, example source code:

```
   <!--in your <Window> or <UserControl> tag -->
  <UserControl
        xmlns:hw="clr-namespace:Project.Namespace.ToClassFile" >
   <!--...-->

    <ListView x:Name="lvImages" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10" Height="auto" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding ListImages}"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <hw:VirtualizingWrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5" MaxHeight="150">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <Image Source="{Binding path, IsAsync=True}" Height="100"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding createDate, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}"/>

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

MVVM style back-end, so this is inside the ViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Media> ListImages
    {
        get
        {
            return listImages;
        }
        set { listImages = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }


     //Just load the images however you do it, then assign it to above list.
//Below is the class defined that I have used.
public class Media
{
    private static int nextMediaId = 1;
    public int mediaId { get; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public DateTime createDate { get; set; }
    public bool isSelected { get; set; }

    public Media()
    {
        mediaId = nextMediaId;
        nextMediaId++;
    }
}
```