# WPF ListBox that lays out its items horizontally

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox

I'm trying to write a WPF application for displaying images from a selection.
I want to display all of the available images in a banner along the top of the window, and display the main selected image in the main window for further processing.

If I wanted the list on the *Left* of the window, displaying the images vertically, I can do this quite elegantly using databinding.

```
    <ListBox 
        Name="m_listBox"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}"            
        >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding}" Width="60" Stretch="Uniform" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Is there a straightforward way I can make this horizontal instead of vertical?
The main requirements of a solution is:

- The items are populated using databinding
- The selected item is changed simply by the user clicking it.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

[WrapPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041551/wpf-listview-with-horizontal-arrangement-of-items)

```
 <ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBoxItem>listbox item 1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>listbox item 2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>listbox item 3</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>listbox item 4</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>listbox item 5</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

[WPF Tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-creating-a-custom-panel-control)

Comment: Or StackPanel with Orientation="Horizontal"

Comment: StackPanel would be the better solution here as Nir said.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, stackPanel with Horizontal orientation is better option.

Comment: Give you +1 on behalf of andrew megs. Who found your code so useful, but didn't want to give you "imaginary internet points"

Answer (score 28):

The default `ItemsPanel` for the `ListBox` control is a `VirtualizingStackPanel`, so if you want the normal, default experience for the control but just have it laid out horizontally, you should specify this (and change the orientation).

Example:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is example of StackPanel.
Horizontal Breadcrumb with Mvvm binding

```
 <ItemsControl
            x:Name="tStack"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Height="40"
            Background="Red"
            ItemsSource="{Binding BreadCrumbs}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button
                        Margin="5"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                        Command="{Binding BreadcrumbClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}, Path=DataContext.BreadcrumbClickCommand}"
                        Content="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```