# A simple image listview

Tags: wpf, listview

I am trying to make a simple dictionary bound image listview where key is `filename` and value is `image path`.

Following is the code

```
<ListView Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Height="131" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,9,0,0" Name="GenreListView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="375">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding}"></Image>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Following is the code for runtime:

```
    Dim maindir As DirectoryInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectoryInfo(CurDir() + "\Icons")
    GenreDictionary.Clear()
    For Each k As FileInfo In maindir.GetFiles()
        If k.Name.EndsWith(".png") Then
            GenreDictionary.Add(k.Name, k.FullName)
        End If
    Next

    'Load Icons to Genre View
    GenreListView1.ItemsSource = GenreDictionary.Values
```

Could you please guide me on how to get the image bound. This is a windows app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a dictionary? Why not just use a list of FileNames? If you do that then your `<Image Source="{Binding"} />` would work. Your code would then look like this:

```
Dim maindir As DirectoryInfo = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectoryInfo(CurDir() + "\Icons")

Dim fileList = as new List<string>();

For Each k As FileInfo In maindir.GetFiles()
    If k.Name.EndsWith(".png") Then
        fileList.Add(k.FullName)
    End If
Next

'Load Icons to Genre View
GenreListView1.ItemsSource = fileList
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm, but now I am faced with one more issue, all the images are arranged in one row only, although wrap panel is there, they are not wrapping, should i use the scrollview, I even tried it but some error is coming up saying that a panel must only be placed in template.  Could you please help me in this.

Comment: This other answer can help you with that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041551/wpf-listview-with-horizontal-arrangement-of-items

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<Image Source="{Binding Value}"/>
```

Comment: ArsenMkrt, thanks for the quick reply, however I am not getting that work still.