# listview wrappanel not working when ungrouped

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, wrappanel

I'm adapting this solution to my needs: http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/08/woring-with-icollectionviewsource-in.html

The XAML part of the listview is:

```
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="lvIcons" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
        ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
        MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, 
        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>

    </ListView>
```

I've got a button to control if I want to show grouped or not and the code behind for this button is:

```
private void btnGroup_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Source.GroupDescriptions.Clear();

        PropertyInfo pinfo = typeof(country_icon).GetProperty(cmbGroups.Text);
        if (pinfo != null)
            this.Source.GroupDescriptions.Add(new ropertyGroupDescription(pinfo.Name));

    }
```

When grouping is on, the wrappanel is working nicely (i'm grouping by an integer property on the icons)

[image: WrappingNicely]

But when grouping is not on, no wrapping:

[image: NotWrappingNicely]

I'm not worried about different sizes of icon's - i'll fix that later.

How do I fix wrapping when not grouped ? Is there a different template in use ?

Thanks to the answer of this question [WPF ListView with horizontal arrangement of items?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041551/wpf-listview-with-horizontal-arrangement-of-items) to help get me to where I am now.

Comment: Quick look, but I would say when you 'ungroup' you should be putting them all in one group to get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Well hey.. that is one way forward. I'll work on that and if a solution is posted, switch. Thanks