# Need to create a ListView that lists a single column of items horizontally across the view

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to create a listview in wpf that has one column of items and list those items horizontally across the view.  I have been unable to find an answer to this and have been searching for quite a while.  Maybe I just can't come up with the correct search term for this.

So, in other words, I would like to make a single listing of strings (i.e. file names) in one column and when the column reaches the height of the list view, instead of creating a vertical scroll bar, creates another column to the right of the first.  Then if there are enough items, a horizontal scroll bar appears.  Such as how the windows explorer does it on the "List" setting.

This is what I have so far.

```
    <ListView x:Name="dirListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="181" Margin="10,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="572" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=selectedItem}">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="TwoParts">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding image}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding directory}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource TwoParts}" />
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I took a look at the answer below as well as the answers in the post suggested below and came up with a new XAML.  I am also trying to bind data to this List View and it doesn't seem to be working.  As you can see above, I tied the data to the DataTemplate and referenced the key of the template to the GridViewColumn.  That doesn't seem to work the same way with this newly suggested way.  Here is what I have now.

The XAML code:

```
    <ListView x:Name="dirListView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="181" Margin="10,43,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="572" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=selectedItem}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding image}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding directory}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"                    
                           MaxHeight="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualHeight), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
                           ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
                           MinHeight="{Binding ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                           ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

The data class containing the data to bind to the ListView:

```
public class ControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<MyDirItems> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<MyDirItems> Items
    { 
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Items"); } 
    }

    private MyDirItems _selectedItem;
    public MyDirItems selectedItem 
    { 
        get { return _selectedItem; } 
        set { _selectedItem = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("selectedItem"); } 
    }

    public ControlViewModel()
    {
        _selectedItem = new MyDirItems();
        Icon icon = FileChooser.GetFolderIcon(IconSize.Small, FolderType.Closed);
        ImageSource i_source = (ImageSource)CommonUtility.ImageUtil.ImageConvert(icon.ToBitmap());
        _items = new ObservableCollection<MyDirItems>();
        Items.Add(new MyDirItems { directory = "Directory1.DIR", image = i_source });
        Items.Add(new MyDirItems { directory = "Directory2.DIR", image = i_source });
    }

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

}
```

Finally, the data object:

```
public class MyDirItems
{
    public string directory { get; set; }
    public ImageSource image { get; set; }
}
```

Again.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I took a look at the suggested answers at the post linked in the answer below, but data binding doesn't seem to work.  I just get a blank List View.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the ItemsPanelTemplate of the ListView to use a WrapPanel.  With its Orientation set to Vertical, I think that would accomplish what you're looking for.

Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041551/wpf-listview-with-horizontal-arrangement-of-items) for more information.