# C# WPF I want one row show for ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Hello I couldn't find how can I make one row only for Listview its two by default I searched some google and I took a look properties in Listview but still couldnt be able to find it. Hope you guys help

```
   <ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="301" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" BorderThickness="1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Basically when I use this code it creates another row to this one and I dont want that so it will show only Name column.

Comment: what does your code look like..? this is that difficult but would require a few lines of code from you .. here is what I did using the code from the bottom answer in this post and it worked for me in the past. 
https://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/697910-forcing-listview-only-one-column

Comment: sorry not going to read this code in comment format edit your question and post your code in your original question

Comment: okay I changed my original question it should be readable now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041551/wpf-listview-with-horizontal-arrangement-of-items

Comment: I tried headerstyle code but I think it doesn't exist in WPF listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create it as a simple itemsControl.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="301" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="142" BorderThickness="1" />
```

I added some sample data to check.

```
listView.ItemsSource = new[] { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };
```

Hope this helps!