# How to show ListView items list like in Winform ListView when View property is set to list?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am implementing listview in wpf.I want to show listview items as checkbox with text.Below is my listview code.

```
<Style TargetType="ListView"  x:Key="ListViewTemplate">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <CheckBox   Margin="0,1,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}" ></CheckBox>
                            <Separator Opacity="0" Width="6" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"  ></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        </Grid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

This make the grid look like

[image]

But I want the grid to look like this

[image]

With a horizontal scroll bar, in case the listview items are large.How do I achieve this?

---

I have tried using wrap panel and stack panel, but they show items only in one direction horizontal or vertical.

Comment: Isn't [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041551/wpf-listview-with-horizontal-arrangement-of-items) what you need ?

Comment: Provide `Width` on `WrapPanel`.

Comment: The link was helpful but I am still not getting spacing  among the listview items right.The look they are cramped together.

Comment: It looks like the Items are not actually placed inside any grid column or row. Maybe you can work out a solution with nested stackpanels