# How to float left for ListView ItemTemplate in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I set float left in ListView?

this is how it looks right now:

[image]

and this is what I want:

[image]

**this is my code behide:**

```
List<MenuItem> menu = new List<Model.MenuItem>();

       menu.Add(new Model.MenuItem("hihi", "123123", "1231231", "123123", "123123"));

       menu.Add(new Model.MenuItem("hihi", "123123", "1231231", "123123", "123123"));

       menu.Add(new Model.MenuItem("hihi", "123123", "1231231", "123123", "123123"));

       ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menu;
```

Comment: can show us your xaml code

Comment: my code xaml  in comment

Comment: This answer have already been asked before, have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041551/wpf-listview-with-horizontal-arrangement-of-items

Comment: @Alen.Toma can you help me editing his question. I can not add his xaml code... it says : "it looks like you added some code without explanation", but i have added explanation too :(

Comment: Where is his XML and also there is already an answer to this, that i already added in my prev comment

Answer (score 0):

If you need the wrapping behavior only than you can add this xaml code in your ListView

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <WrapPanel/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```