# How i can put more columns into a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

So i am trying to fill a ListView with a UserControl that i've made.

But when i fill the ListView it's shows one column per cell, how i can fix it?

[One picture to describe it more carefully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ems5.png)

This is the code i am using, io tried with AllowsColumnReorder but it doesn't reorder it by the listview itself. How i can do it?

**XML**

```
<ListView Name="myListView" Style="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.ListView}">
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}"
            ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}"
            MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True">
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:GalleryButton Height="100" Width="150"></local:GalleryButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        List<GalleryButton> butons = new List<GalleryButton>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            GalleryButton b = new GalleryButton();
            butons.Add(b);
        }

        myListView.Items.Clear();
        myListView.ItemsSource = null;
        myListView.ItemsSource = butons;
}
```

Comment: What is expected result? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1041551/1997232) ?

Comment: but when i am using this                                                              
           <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>                                                                                           I can't load my test list to the ItemSource

Comment: Try complete solution from accepted answer. `WrapPanel` require its width defined, otherwise it can't lay out children, therefore all those bindings are important. If you still have a problem simply ask a new question, make sure to add [mcve].

Comment: Okay i will do the minimal reproducible example

Comment: it's edited, so you can review it better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you're trying to use a vertical `WrapPanel` in a control with vertical scrolling. You will always only see one column this way.

And since you are displaying a list of Buttons, you probably don't need to use a `ListView`.

You might consider using a simple `ItemsControl` instead. The XAML is very similar, and you can more easily control scrolling because you provide the `ScrollViewer`.

Unless you have a hard requirement that your items wrap vertically, I would highly recommend (from a UX perspective) wrapping your items horizontally. That is more in-line with what most applications do.

Comment: i am trying to do a Button to acces into a 3D model, and then this goes for the gallery of the 3D Models

Comment: Thank you for your help, now i've got the correct gallery i will post my solution for everyone

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was that i was not getting correctly how to do it, thnaks to @Keithernet i got how to fix it, this is the code

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="myListView" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="5"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Rows="{Binding Path=Rows, Mode=TwoWay}" Columns="{Binding Path=Columns, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:GalleryButton></local:GalleryButton>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate >
                <Border x:Name="Border"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ScrollViewer Margin="0"
                                  Focusable="False"
                                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                  CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll}">
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Silver" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

**Code-Behind**

```
public partial class ModelGallery : UserControl
{
    public int Rows { get; set; }
    public int Columns { get; set; }

    public ModelGallery()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        myListView.Items.Clear();
    }

    public void setModelList(List<GalleryButton> llista)
    {
        Columns = 5;
        Rows = llista.Count / Columns;
        myListView.ItemsSource = llista;
    }
}
```

So i was needing a ControlTemplate to get all correct with a ScrollViwer, all the other stuff was very intuitive, so what we need? a Template to watch the items and then show it. then we only need to render a Scroll.
Thanks for all your help.