# Timeline control in C#

Tags: c#, timeline, packets

I am implementing a packet analyzer in C#. I need a timeline control which would display the packets on a line, and they would be selectable. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuTFy.png). Are there ready made controls like this in C#?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any restrictions on the license? Also, free or paid? Also, WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Preferably free. No restrictions on the license. WPF.

Answer (score 0):

If you're implementing this as a GUI, you could use WPF and add items to a listbox, using a custom layout to make it [display horizontally](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CustomListBoxLayoutInWPF.aspx). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359217/how-do-i-make-wpf-listview-items-repeat-horizontally-like-a-horizontal-scrollbar) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [.NET chart control](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&displaylang=en)  - has a timeline sample. [Zedgraph](http://www.zedgraph.org) might need a bit more work.