# Arranging ListView items Horizontally

Tags: wpf, listview

I am working with a ListView which is grouped on one of the properties (Resource) of Data Source. My requirement is to display each group aligned horizontally with other groups but my implementation (as below) shows the groups aligned veritcally

```
            <ListView x:Name="listViewResourceHours" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" SelectionMode="Single" Height="100" Width="300" >
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <ContentPresenter/>
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel> 
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0" Content="{Binding Hours}" />
                        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="2,0,0,0" Content="{Binding WorkingHoursType, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=hoursTypeConverter}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Here is a sample of what this code results:

```
PSE: 0 (B) 0 (NB)
PSC: 0 (B) 0 (NB)
PM: 0 (B) 0 (NB)
EIA: 0 (B) 0 (NB)
```

Here is a sample of what I actually want it to look like

```
PSE: 0 (B) 0 (NB)  PSC: 0 (B) 0 (NB)  PM: 0 (B) 0 (NB)  EIA: 0 (B) 0 (NB)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Others may find [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359217/how-do-i-make-wpf-listview-items-repeat-horizontally-like-a-horizontal-scrollba) also helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final code after following gaurawerma

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewResourceHours" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" SelectionMode="Single" Height="100" Width="500" >
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat={}{0}:}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <ContentPresenter Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                    <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0" Content="{Binding Hours}" />
                    <Label Name="lblWorkingHours" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Content="{Binding WorkingHoursType, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=hoursTypeConverter}}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 9):

In this case you should define the Panel for Group as well like:

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

After the mod your xaml looks like:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewResourceHours" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" SelectionMode="Single" Height="100" Width="300" >
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <ContentPresenter/>
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0" Content="{Binding Hours}" />
                <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="2,0,0,0" Content="{Binding WorkingHoursType}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do it, is:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="4" Name="btView"> 
    <ListView.ItemsPanel> 
        <ItemsPanelTemplate> 
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel> 
        </ItemsPanelTemplate> 
    </ListView.ItemsPanel> 
    <ListView.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate> 
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"> 
                <RadioButton Name="Octave1" Content="Octave 1"/> 
                <RadioButton Name="Octave2" Content="Octave 2"/> 
                <RadioButton Name="Octave3" Content="Octave 3"/> 
                <RadioButton Name="Octave4" Content="Octave 4"/> 
            </StackPanel> 
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ListView.ItemTemplate> 

    <ListItem/> 
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ListBox Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBoxItem Content="aaaaaaaaaaa"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="aaaaaaaaaaa"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="aaaaaaaaaaa"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="aaaaaaaaaaa"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="aaaaaaaaaaa"/>
    </ListBox>
```