# WPF Listview Item alignment

Tags: wpf, listview

I'm fairly new to WPF.

And i want to know how to align items side by side but still Horizontal.

So lets sat this is my items right now:

```
( 0 ) ( 0 ) ( 0 ) ( 0 ) ( 0 )
```

But if there isn't more space it will just show a scrollbar instead of continuing on the next line like this:

```
( 0 ) ( 0 ) ( 0 )
( 0 ) ( 0 )
```

This is my XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewResourceHours" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" SelectionMode="Single" Height="100" Width="500" >
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat={}{0}:}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <ContentPresenter Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    <ItemsPresenter Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <Label VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0" Content="{Binding Hours}" />
                <Label Name="lblWorkingHours" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Content="{Binding WorkingHoursType, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=hoursTypeConverter}}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

</ListView>
```

The code is from this question:

[Arranging ListView items Horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10731763/arranging-listview-items-horizontally)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `WrapPanel` with a fixed size or the size of your `ListViewItem`.

Comment: <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="90">
<Label VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0" Content="{Binding Hours}" />
                <Label Name="lblWorkingHours" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Content="{Binding WorkingHoursType, Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=hoursTypeConverter}}" />
                                </WrapPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

Doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: well it still doesn't work when i change the Orientation to Vertical

Comment: it doesn't go down to the next line

Comment: Try putting a `WrapPanel` inside `<ItemsPanelTemplate>`

Comment: still doesn't work, when i select an item i can see the height of item is filling the whole thing, instead of just creating a small box..

Comment: Ah well should have seen that, my fault!

Answer (score 1):

what about a wrappanel?

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```