# Uwp Grouped GridView with WrapGrid

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp, windows-store

I'm developing an UWP app and I'm trying to align horizontally my items in each gridview groups

I have this :

```
GROUP 1

Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3

Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3

Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3

GROUP 2

Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3

Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3
```

and I want this :

```
GROUP 1

______________________________Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3

______________________________Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3

______________________________Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3

GROUP 2

______________________________Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3

______________________________Data 1 | Data 2 | Data 3
```

I order to align my items I use a WrapGrid.
I also tried with a non grouped gridview and my code works fine.

```
<GridView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupBycodeFamille}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTempateCatalogue}">
<GridView.GroupStyle>
<GroupStyle>
<GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:GroupInfoList">
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
</DataTemplate>
</GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
</GroupStyle>
</GridView.GroupStyle>
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
<WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get what you want by setting [`GroupStyle.Panel` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.groupstyle.panel.aspx). This property sets a template that creates the panel used to lay out the items. But [`GridViewItem` has two templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt299127.aspx), when the `GridView`'s `ItemsPanel` is an `ItemsWrapGrid` (the default) or `ItemsStackPanel`, `GridViewItem` uses the template which uses a `GridViewItemPresenter` instead of a `UIElement` tree to improve grid performance. And while using this template, setting `GroupStyle.Panel` property won't affect the `GridView`. We need `GridViewItem` use its second template by setting `GridView`'s `ItemsPanel` to some other `Panel`. As your group is aligned vertically, we can set `GridView`'s `ItemsPanel` to:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Then we can set `GroupStyle.Panel` with a left `Margin` to achieve your goal. But please note that:

> The root element of the template declared for the **ItemsPanelTemplate** in the **GroupStyle.Panel** property **cannot** be a **virtualizing panel**. Virtualizing panels are defined as any type that derives from `VirtualizingPanel`, for example the `VirtualizingStackPanel` class.

So we can't use `WrapGrid` here, we can use a `StackPanel` but the items will be arranged into a single line. To arrange items into multi lines, we need a `Panel` like `WrapPanel` in WPF. We can customize it or use a third party `WrapPanel` like what in **[WinRTXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit)**. Using WinRTXamlToolkit for example:

```
xmlns:toolkit="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"

<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <toolkit:WrapPanel Margin="200,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

The complete XAML code may like:

```
<GridView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupBycodeFamille}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTempateCatalogue}">
    <GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModels:GroupInfoList">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Margin="200,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </GridView.GroupStyle>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Following is the output when I tested in my side:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer and spending time for me, you solded my issue !
Nevertheless I have a large set of data and this solution is very slow, and I saw that SemanticZoom doen't work also. Have you got an idea ?

Comment: I can only imagine how difficult it would be to tap that Checkbox :)