# UWP listview groups style

Tags: c#, listview, uwp

I am creating UWP application. There is a listview, with groups.

XAML code goes like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="ContactsCVS"  IsSourceGrouped="True" />

    <!-- When using x:Bind, you need to set x:DataType -->
    <DataTemplate x:Name="ContactListViewTemplate" x:DataType="data:Contact">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Ellipse x:Name="Ellipse"
                     Grid.RowSpan="2"
                     Width ="32"
                     Height="32"
                     Margin="6"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                     Fill="LightGray"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{x:Bind Name}" 
                       x:Phase="1"  
                       Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}"
                       Margin="12,6,0,0"/>
            <TextBlock  Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Text="{x:Bind Position}" 
                        x:Phase="2"
                        Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                        Margin="12,0,0,6"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ContactsCVS.View}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactListViewTemplate}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True"
              Grid.Row="1"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2" x:Name="listViewMain">

        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GroupInfoList">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}" 
                                   />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And everything is ok, except that I want to make each group to have some kind of border. Like this:

[image: [1]]


How to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UWP ListView main header group style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43537275/uwp-listview-main-header-group-style)

Comment: Nope. That one is for header item style, this is for group style.

Comment: Replace the ItemsPanelTemplate in the GroupStyle https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GroupStyle

Answer (score 1):

As @Ken Tucker said, you can edit the `GroupStyle` and use [GroupStyle.Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.GroupStyle#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_GroupStyle_Panel) property to add a border for each group. For example, using a `GroupStyle` like the following:

```
<GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GroupInfoList">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}"
                       Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    <GroupStyle.Panel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" Margin="8,0,18,0" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.Panel>
</GroupStyle>
```

However, you may find there is no effect with using this `GroupStyle` in your code. This is because `GroupStyle.Panel` can't work with UI virtualization. If the `ListView` uses a virtualizing panel such as [ItemsWrapGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsWrapGrid) or [ItemsStackPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ItemsStackPanel), then `GroupStyle.Panel` won't have effect. And for `ListView` its default `ItemsPanel` is a `ItemsStackPanel`. So you will also need to change `ListView`'s `ItemsPanel` like:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Then you should be able to see the border for each group. For more info, please refer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33818281/5506161). And also please note that using `GroupStyle.Panel` might influence the performance as the lack of UI virtualization. You may consider whether to use this according to your real scenario.