# need to set gridview alignement horizontally instead of vertically

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-store-apps

I'd like to set my gridview to fill it [horizontally](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yrwre0woom4bw5b/Untitled2.png?dl=0) instead of [vertically](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s8cz8ny37w0aysh/Untitled.png?dl=0) I don't find any information about this.
Could you suggest me how can solve this issue.
I'd appreciate your help. Thanks.

Thank you

Comment: This is the link to access to the XAML 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/s6ia5byty1x65oj/MainPage.xaml?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `ListView` with its `ItemsPanel` set to `ItemsWrapGrid` with `Orientation="Horizontal"`. Otherwise you could try to flip scrolling direction of a `GridView` in a reverse way to what I suggested in my answer to the question below:

[Windows 8 ListView with horizontal item flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334981/windows-8-listview-with-horizontal-item-flow)

Answer (score 0):

I Find my solution with you answer. it was not totally the answer but here is the code to add for what I want :

```html
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsPanelTemplate>

          <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"    MaximumRowsOrColumns="4"/>
     </ItemsPanelTemplate>
```