# UseOptimizedManipulationRouting in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

For a Windows Phone 8.1 app, I have a horizontal listview inside a listview inside a pivot, like this:

```
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem>
        <Listview>
           <Listview.Itemtemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                   <Listview>
```

The "deepest" listview is oriented horizontally, by using a horizontal stackpanel as itemspaneltemplate.
I want this listview to scroll horizontally, and I found out that I should use the property UseOptimizedManipulationRouting. The only thing that's unclear for me is on which element it should be used. I tried it on the inner listview and the pivot, but on none of them intellisense suggested it, and when I added it manually, it wouldn't compile. Am I missing a reference or something? Did I try adding it on the wrong element?

Comment: [The docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.windows.frameworkelement.useoptimizedmanipulationrouting(v=vs.105).aspx) say to put it on the inner control. Are you building for Silverlight or Universal? Also this is not WPF (please remove the tag)

Comment: I am building for 8.1 Universal. Removed the tag.

Comment: Have you tried [HorizontalScrollMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollmode.aspx)?

Comment: That was the problem, yes. I used this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334981/windows-8-listview-with-horizontal-item-flow thread and that solved it. You can submit that as an answer if you want, and ill approve it

Comment: I voted to close as a dupe instead.