# Set properties on multiple controls on multiple grids

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, powershell

I have a XAML file with 12 grids, each containing an identical set of labels.  They're named grid1, mainLabel1, otherLabel1, countLabel1; grid2, mainLabel2, etc.  I have a collection of projects held in a List(T) collection (List(Projects)).  Each element in the list will contain text to be held in the labels.  I also need to get a count for how many elements are in the list and hide all the grids that are outside that range (i.e. if there are 8 projects in the list, hide grids 9-12).

I've done this in Powershell, but I need to get it into a C#/XAML file for future-proofing for my team.  In PS, I can use Get-Variable with -ValueOnly to assign values to properties of controls, but I can't seem to find a way to do this in C#.  Admittedly, I'm very new to C#, so any guidance would be appreciated.

I've thought of using a for or foreach loop, because then I could use i in each iteration, but it seems problematic for working with the control names.

Here's a sampling of the working Powershell.  After this setup and a couple other lines, I can use $f.Add_Click or $b.Add_Click and set up a script block.  How to do this in C#?

```
foreach ($i in $script:projects)
{
    $n = $script:projects.IndexOf($i) + 1
    $m = $script:projects.IndexOf($i)

    # get new variables based on existing control names
    $a = Get-Variable -Name "WPFprojBG$n" -ValueOnly
    $b = Get-Variable -Name "WPFgrid$n" -ValueOnly
    $c = Get-Variable -Name "WPFclientLabel$n" -ValueOnly
    $d = Get-Variable -Name "WPFprojLabel$n" -ValueOnly
    $e = Get-Variable -Name "WPFcount$n" -ValueOnly
    $f = Get-Variable -Name "WPFButton$n" -ValueOnly
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea with WPF is that when you display a collection, you bind it to a collection-capable control and override its templates to show each item (in your case, Project) in the format you want. One control that might help you out is the [ListView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750972(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0). See [this tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-data-binding-item-template/) for a tutorial of how to do so.

Comment: Hmm...Maybe I didn't explain the visual piece well.  The grids are set up like this: http://i.imgur.com/KcvbDh8.png  Each green area is a grid, each red block and "1" are text boxes that are part of the grid underneath it.  Top left is grid1, label1, otherLabel1, count1.  To the right of it is grid2, label2, etc.  I'm not sure if the ListView tutorial here really helps...or am I missing what you're trying to tell me?

Comment: Ok, with that end result in mind it looks like you just want the ListView to flow items across the window horizontally.  Each of your green areas would represent an item in your list and you would lay out their content controls in an itemtemplate, as in the tutorial under the section "ListView with an ItemTemplate".  See [this SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11345736/3407841) for an example of how to make a horizontal listview style.  Combine those two and change the itemtemplate to match your own layout and voila.

Comment: This will be a long road for me, but it's definitely the right one.  Thanks for the info!