# How to set ListView column dynamically?

Tags: wpf

I have simple List. 
I need to define Table that each column of this table is one of this list elements.

So i will use ListView - I need to define a ListView that each column of this ListView is one of my List => that mean that the

first column name is List[0]
second column name is List[1]
.
.
.

I can't fine any way to do it.
I google it and all the examples are shown how to create dynamic rows

Any help please ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may style your ListView with items layed out horizontally.

Like this:

```
<ListView>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <TextBlock>Column 1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>Column 2</TextBlock>
  </ListView>
```

See this: [How do I make WPF ListView items repeat horizontally, like a horizontal scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359217/how-do-i-make-wpf-listview-items-repeat-horizontally-like-a-horizontal-scrollba)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want a ListView with a GridView setup to do this. For example:

From http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-with-gridview/

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTutorialSamples.ListView_control.ListViewGridViewSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ListViewGridViewSample" Height="200" Width="400">
    <Grid>
                <ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers">
                        <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                                        <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
                                </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
        </Grid>
</Window>
```

Once you have the GridView, then adding columns is as simple as adding GridViewColumn to the GridView's Columns collection.

From http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/gridview-in-wpf/

```
private void CreateDynamicGridView()
{
    // Create a GridView 
    GridView grdView = new GridView();
    grdView.AllowsColumnReorder = true;
    grdView.ColumnHeaderToolTip = "Authors";

    GridViewColumn nameColumn = new GridViewColumn();
    nameColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Name");
    nameColumn.Header = "Author Name";
    nameColumn.Width = 120;
    grdView.Columns.Add(nameColumn);

    GridViewColumn ageColumn = new GridViewColumn();
    ageColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Age");
    ageColumn.Header = "Age";
    ageColumn.Width = 30;
    grdView.Columns.Add(ageColumn);

    GridViewColumn bookColumn = new GridViewColumn();
    bookColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Book");
    bookColumn.Header = "Book";
    bookColumn.Width = 250;
    grdView.Columns.Add(bookColumn);

    GridViewColumn mvpColumn = new GridViewColumn();
    mvpColumn.DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Mvp");
    mvpColumn.Header = "Mvp";
    mvpColumn.Width = 50;
    grdView.Columns.Add(mvpColumn);

    ListView1.View = grdView;
}
```