# Listview in WinRT using C#

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime

I want my ListView to display the items in a group horizontally as displayed in the image below. I could not find anything relating to this online. This screen was taken from the Groove music application. Since I am new to asking questions here it seems I don't have enough reputation to post images therefore I provided a link to the image in question sorry for the inconvenience.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1K3q.png

Edit:
I am trying to imitate the groove music player for a school project this link below shows my app. Hopefully this give you a better idea of the problem.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/whchY.png

My Xaml Code:
`<ListView
                x:Name="itemGridView"

                Grid.Row="1"

                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource artistsItemsViewSource}}"
                SelectionMode="None"
                IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                RequestedTheme="Light">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel MaxWidth="200">

                                <Ellipse Height="150" Width="150">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Assets/Artist.png"/>
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ArtistName}" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,5,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlbumCount}" FontSize="15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                            <ItemsStackPanel Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,0,0,0"/>

                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>

                <ListView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,2">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AlphaLetter}" FontSize="20" Foreground="{StaticResource SideButtonBlue}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListView.GroupStyle>

            </ListView>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make WPF ListView items repeat horizontally, like a horizontal scrollbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359217/how-do-i-make-wpf-listview-items-repeat-horizontally-like-a-horizontal-scrollba)

Comment: This causes all groups be organized horizontally and not just the items within a group of the listview.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did actually wrote a simple DataTemplate for your ListView?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the view in the listview settings to `LargeIcon` and then you can set Icons for each value in your listview.

But you could maybe use the ObjectListView its better than the plain ListView and you have more functions. check this out: [click](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView)

I found something similar on the site of the objectlistview: [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView/foobar-lookalike.png)

Answer (score 0):

for horizontal placement of the elements in `ListView` do this:

```
 <ItemsStackPanel
 Orientation="Horizontal" />
```

also, remove `Width="200"` 
also you can use `GridView` instead of `ListView`