# Horizontal ListView on multiple lines (WPF)

Tags: wpf, stackpanel, file-browser, horizontallist

I want to implement an horizontal `ListView` which can have multiple lines, like the file explorer:

[image]

I found that I have to use `StackPanel`for the `ItemPanelTemplate` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359418/2993413), but I prefer to have multiple lines instead of the horizontal scrollbar.
I think that the idea is *when the StackPanel width reaches the ListView width, go the next line/create a new StackPanel*. I don't know if it's correct, but maybe it can help to understand what am I looking for.

How can I implement this?

Comment: If listview is not compulsory then you should go with wrap panel.

Comment: Put a wrap panel as the itemspanel of a listbox or itemscontrol. Like this does: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33327.wpf-wrappanel-itemspanel-last-of-line.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `WrapPanel` instead of a `StackPanel` as `ItemsPanelTemplate`.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding xxx}">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `WrapPanel` and specify the `width`.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="your-source">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel width="1200" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```