# Xamarin Forms - how to create a Horizontal ListView in xaml?

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How to create Horizontal listview that has maximum of 3 row and more column it depends on the data just like in this picture

[image: Concept]
Link:https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUJjB.jpg

**This is my concept don't mind the design i just want to know how to create that kind of list view**

Comment: Looks like a grid inside a scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `FlexLayout`.

> FlexLayout is similar to the Xamarin.Forms StackLayout in that it can
>   arrange its children horizontally and vertically in a stack. However,
>   the FlexLayout is also capable of wrapping its children if there are
>   too many to fit in a single row or column, and also has many options
>   for orientation, alignment, and adapting to various screen sizes.

More information can be found in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout).

Answer (score 1):

Set the ItemsPanel of the ListView to a horizontal StackPanel.

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359217/how-do-i-make-wpf-listview-items-repeat-horizontally-like-a-horizontal-scrollba).

**Edit: This solution may actually not work for you.** If it doesn't work, take a look at this [library](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView). It might help you.

Comment: I down-voted your answer, because there is no ‘ItemsPanelTemplate’ available in XF, no need to mention it as possible solution. Regarding your question, ask Jeremy Paul if it is working not me.

Comment: @EvZ you too are important